# How to get the imagenet dataset on which pytorch models are trained on

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, imagenet

***Can anyone please tell me how to download the complete imagenet dataset on which the pytorch torchvision models are trained on and their Top-1 error is reported on?***

I have downloaded Tiny-Imagenet from Imagenet website and used pretrained resnet-101 model which provides only 18% Top-1 accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Download the ImageNet dataset from http://www.image-net.org/  (you have to sign in)

Then, you should move validation images to labeled subfolders, which could be done automatically using the following shell script:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soumith/imagenetloader.torch/master/valprep.sh